# Adding column in dataframe through loop and populate according to content in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I  have the following dataframe (New_Data) and I want to add a new column depending on the content of column 'merchant'. For example if 'merchant' contains 'AMZ' or 'AMZN', I want the column to return 'Amazon', if 'merchant' contains 'PRIME', I want the column to return 'Video' and so on and so forth until the last row. I would like to do this through a loop.

I have attempted the following which creates a column but I dont know how to combine loop with content if-function:

```
merchantlength=len(New_Data[['Merchant']])
merchantlength
i=0
for i in range(merchantlength):
    df['newcolumn']="1"

New_Data = pd.concat([ df], axis=1) 
New_Data
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3nyR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to use looping?

Look at Numpy select function.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

```
condlist = [
    df['merchant'] == 'AMZ',
    df['merchant'] == 'PRIME',
]
choicelist = [
    'Amazon',
    'Video'
]
df['newcol'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Comment: The problem is that I dont know the full content of all the cells. Is there a function that will append 'Amazon' if the content in 'merchant' contains any characters 'AMZ'. In your solution you need to know exactly the content. For example, if it is not equal exactly to 'AMZ', it will not return anything.

Comment: You may use df[‘merchant’].str.contains('AMZ', regex=False) or df[‘merchant’].str.contains('AMZ|Any|Sub|String', regex=True)

Comment: Thanks, that worked without the need for a loop as you mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to add some data in the new_column based on the value of "merchant" column so try doing this:

```
values = []    
for i in df['merchant']:
        if i=='AMZ':
            values.append('Amazon')
        elif i == 'prime':
             values.append('video')
```

after adding every possible category values just append this list as new column with some name as

```
df['new_column'] = values
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. It partially works. The problem is that I dont know the full content of all the cells. Is there a function that will append 'Amazon' if the content in 'merchant' contains 'AMZ'.

Comment: To clarify, i need to return 'Amazon' if the cells contains any characters 'AMZ' or 'AMZNMKTPLACE'.

Comment: Try printing the value_counts such that it will print unique values in that column then try above solution